# Automatically use Timestamp in Laravel 5.4 Query builder

Tags: laravel, timestamp, laravel-5.4

is there any way to automatically use time-stamp when using query builder, currently I'm using CARBON.
here is my code:

```
DB::table('product_in_out')->insert(
                ['product_id'                   => $product_id,
                 'warehouse_id'                 => $warehouse_id, 
                 'balance_before'               => Product::getProductBalanceOf($action_id, $product_id),
                 'in'                           => $product_qty,
                 'out'                          => '0',
                 'after_balance'                => Product::getProductBalanceOf($action_id, $product_id)+$product_qty,
                 'action'                       => 'ProcurementReceipt',
                 'action_id'                    => $action_id,
                 'created_by'                   => auth()->user()->id,
                 'updated_by'                   => auth()->user()->id,
                 'is_active'                    => '1',
                 'created_at'                   =>  \Carbon\Carbon::now(), # \Datetime()
                 'updated_at'                   => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),# \Datetime() ]

            );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fields `created_at` and `update_at` are part of Eloquent.

You need to use Eloquent instead of query builder to insert and update the record in to database for automatic time handling. Eloquent will handle auto update of updated_at column for you,

here is the way,

If you have model name Product,

```
$product = new Product();
$product->column_name = $column_value;
....
...
$product->save();
```

Above code will add time stamp automatically at `created_at` and `updated_at` column.

Now use Eloquent to update your records like,

```
$product = Product::find($id);
$product->update_column_name = $update_value;
...
...
$product->update();
```

This will update your `updated_at` column value accordingly.

Hope you understand.

Comment: I got your point, so it means that the automatic timestamp is in eloquent only ?

Comment: @MartneyAcha Yes, with query builder you have to do it manually

Comment: @MartneyAcha I'm happy it helped you. I thing even with model bulk insert or update has some problem with time stamp

Answer (score 0):

Use Laravel Macros:
https://medium.com/fattihkoca/laravel-auto-save-timestamps-with-query-builder-without-using-eloquent-123f7ebfeb92

It is wise to create a macro to avoid typing the same things every time.

1. `insertTs` method inserting records into database with `created_at` data:

`DB::table('users')->insertTs([
   'email' => 'john@example.com'
]);`

`$id = DB::table('users')->insertGetIdTs([
   'email' => 'john@example.com'
]);`

2. `updateTs` method updating records into database with `updated_at` data:

`DB::table('users')
   ->where('id', 1)
   ->updateTs(['email' => 'john@example.com']);`

3. `deleteTs` method deleting records into database with `deleted_at` data (soft delete):

`DB::table('users')
   ->where('id', 1)
   ->deleteTs();`